# Name of a book about a spaceship after civilization falls

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I remember a book series where humans had spread out in space but a disease that affected machines (and then somehow transitioned to biological infection through human implants) caused civilization to collapse. The story takes place long after the fall, when survivors on earth rebuild using salvaged technology. The spaceship in question is testing some new technology and gets transported across the stars causing damage that kills some of the crew. They then encounter several other human remnant civilizations and warlords.

Comment: Possibly one of the Revelation Space novels or stories; https://revelationspace.fandom.com/wiki/Melding_Plague

Comment: @Valorum Does anyone in the Revelation Space series ever travel to Earth?

Comment: @Raj - Worthy of its own question ("*What is the current status of Earth"*) but the short answer is that Earth appears to be uninhabitable during the events of the early Revelation Space novels and stories. Eventually it's destroyed by the Greenfly.